# Update a session var with AJAX in Woocommerce

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing a function in Woocommerce where it receives a variable with `WC () -> session-> get ('shipping_calculated_cost')` but what I want is that as soon as that hook is activated, the price of the message is refreshed by means of the `woocommerce_package_rates` function. Currently what happens to me is that it takes the value of the session variable but it is updated when I select the next element of the `dropdownlist` refreshes the first saved value.

For example, if the value selected in `$cost` is 10, it stores it but does not show it. When I select another value it shows the value that was previously selected, which in this case would be 10.

In this function the value of `$cost` is a number given by a `dropdownlist`, in this case I put a value of 10. Also, it has active `AJAX` to be updated.

```
function guardar_variable(){
  $costo = 10;
  WC()->session->set( 'shipping_calculated_cost', $costo );
  foreach ( WC()->cart->get_shipping_packages() as $package_key => $package ):
      WC()->session->set( 'shipping_for_package_' . $package_key, false );
  endforeach;

  header('Content-type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($costo);
  die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_guardar_variable','guardar_variable',9);
add_action('wp_ajax_guardar_variable','guardar_variable',9);
```

This function receives the value that will be stored in the session var.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'adjust_shipping_rate', 11 );
function adjust_shipping_rate( $rates ){

  foreach ($rates as $rate):
      $cost = $rate->cost;
      $rate->cost = WC()->session->get( 'shipping_calculated_cost' );
  endforeach;

  return $rates;
}
```

In my JS Script I have the following line to refresh the page. In doing so, it refreshes 2 times. And it can not be updated once. This brings me as a problem is the delay in the burden of payment and shipping.

```
$('body').trigger('update_checkout');
```